# Java: Check what processes are bound to a port?

Tags: java, exception, netbeans, binding, port

I am developing an application in Netbeans, and it is using JavaDB. I can connect to it and execute queries without issues, but for some reason, the "Output - JavaDB Database Process" pane within Netbeans keeps displaying

```
Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Could not listen on port 1527 on host localhost:
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

How do I **find out what process** is already using, or **bound to that port**?

---

On Ubuntu Karmic, Netbeans 6.7.1

Comment: please specify your OS, simplest ways for that are OS-specific

Comment: @John Feminella : I'm on Ubuntu Karmic

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To find the pid of a process listening to the port 1527, either use:

```
$ netstat -ap | grep 1527
tcp6       0      0 localhost:1527          [::]:*                  LISTEN      31962/java
```

or

```
$ lsof -i :1527
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    31962 pascal   28u  IPv6 13413903      0t0  TCP localhost:1527 (LISTEN)
```

And then:

```
$ ps aux | grep 31962 | grep -v grep
pascal   31962  0.1  0.2 674936  4172 pts/1    Sl   May08   1:23 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java -classpath /usr/share/javadb/lib/derby.jar:/usr/share/javadb/lib/derbynet.jar:/usr/share/javadb/lib/derbytools.jar:/usr/share/javadb/lib/derbyclient.jar org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl start
```

And I'm pretty sure that what you'll find is the pid of a Java process corresponding to JavaDB (I don't know many processes using port 1527 apart from JavaDB). How did you actually start it?

PS: I'm using JavaDB that I'm starting on the command line, outside any IDE.

Comment: +1 and check @Pascal Thivent : Thanks for the answer, was spot on!

Comment: > How did you actually start it?
Well I checked the PPID, and it looked as if Netbeans had two instances of JavaDB runnign at once (I don't know how that happened) - it usually only has one.

Comment: If you don't know the port or have multiple, you can run this instead of the first command to get the list of PIDs. `netstat -ap | grep tcp | grep java | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $7}' | sed 's-/java--' | sort | uniq` If anyone knows of a way to then pipe this into the third part please comment. I think a lot of people run into this and having it all as a one liner is super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Two programs that would help you out are ‘lsof‘ and ‘netstat‘ both of which can provide this information. I would give you the arguments to call them with but I am using my oversized iPhone to answer and it is too cumbersome to look up. So that is left as an exercise for the reader ;-)